# Утечка памяти в джаве в коде соединения с БД

Tags: java, spring, утечка-памяти

Я пытаюсь найти утечку памяти в приложении. Во время нагрузки приложения мы сделали дамп памяти и загрузили его в плагин Memory Analyzer для Eclipse. Плагин выдает такой результат:

```
One instance of "com.rethinkdb.net.Connection" loaded by "jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader @ 0x800007f8" occupies 331 482 280 (94,61%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
com.rethinkdb.net.Connection
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]
jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader @ 0x800007f8
```

Здесь `Connection` это соединение с БД. Оно создается таким образом:

```
import com.rethinkdb.RethinkDB;
import com.rethinkdb.net.Connection;

public class DBConnector {

    private static DBConnector instance;
    private Connection connection;

    private DBConnector() {
        connection = RethinkDB.r.connection().hostname("127.0.0.1").connect();
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public static DBConnector getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBConnector();
        }
        else if (!instance.getConnection().isOpen()) {
            instance = new DBConnector();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Единственное место в программе, где используется соединение, это репозитории:

```
import com.rethinkdb.RethinkDB;
import com.rethinkdb.model.MapObject;
import com.rethinkdb.net.Connection;
import com.rethinkdb.net.Cursor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import project.domain.act.CommercialAct;
import project.general.util.ReturnType;
import project.general.util.Time;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public class ActRepository {

    @Autowired
    private RethinkDB r;

    @Autowired
    private Connection conn;

    @Value("${rethinkdb.database}")
    private String database;

    @Value(("${rethinkdb.commercial_act}"))
    private String table;

    public ReturnType create(CommercialAct act) {

        conn = DBConnector.getInstance().getConnection();

        r.db(database).table(table).insert(
                r.hashMap()
                        .with("senderDateTime", act.getSenderDateTime())

    }

    public Optional<CommercialAct> find(String uid) {

        conn = DBConnector.getInstance().getConnection();

        Cursor cursor = r.db(database).table(table)
                .getAll(uid).optArg("index", "uid")
                .run(conn);


    }

    public ReturnType update(CommercialAct act) {

        conn = DBConnector.getInstance().getConnection();

        MapObject doc = r.hashMap()
                .with("senderDateTime", act.getSenderDateTime())

    }
}
```

Для краткости я удалил лишний код из методов.

Каким образом здесь могут утекать объекты? Как это исправить?

Comment: Если `Connection` аннотировано как `@Autowired`, зачем явно получать его из `DBConnector.getInstance().getConnection()`?

Comment: @gooamoko, Autowired был нужен раньше. Сейчас потребовалось, чтобы после обрыва соединения его можно было получить снова. Autowireв не позволяет сделать это просто (например, не применяя рефлексию)

Comment: Не работал с RethinkDB, но кажется странным еще вот что. В классе явно @Autoware-ится RethinkDB (r), а так же он используется в `DBConnector`. Почему не сделать DBConnector Spring-бином? Они же вроде как синглтоны по умолчанию.

Comment: `conn.close()` разве не нужно вызывать?

Comment: В методе `getInstance()` можно объединить 2 условия, т.к. при их выполнении выполняется один и тот же блок. Извините за тавтологию. Хотя, это отступление и скорее всего не есть причиной утечки

Comment: Нигде не вижу инициализации `r` - по идее это же должна быть `final static`... Подозреваю утечку где-то в районе этого...

Comment: `Сursor` надо закрывать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже, что утечка происходит из-за того, что Вы не закрываете Cursor:

```
 Cursor cursor = r.db(database).table(table)
            .getAll(uid).optArg("index", "uid")
            .run(conn);
```

Объект Connection хранит в себе кэш курсоров.
Когда вызывается `Cursor.close()`, курсор удаляется из кэша в объекте Connection.

См. исходный код: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rethinkdb/net/Cursor.java#L50

Таким образом, если Вы никогда не закрываете курсоры, размер кэша постоянно растёт, и в конце-концов, занимает всю свободную память -> OOM error.

Также кэш курсоров можно очистить вызвав `close()` на самом объекте Connection: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rethinkdb/net/Connection.java#L148